# Windows Phone 8 via USB does not display in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I was working on my windows 8.1 OS on my Virtual Box running Visual Studio 2012.  Yes I am working on an 8.0 with a feature and after planned on migrating everything to 8.1 since it can be integrated more easily with PC And tablet.  Everything was working fine and my windows phone 8 was connected via my virtual box via USB and showed up in VS2012.  My Virtual Box did 2 random shutdowns and now my VS2012 only shows an option to use an emulator.  This was never working before which is why I always debugged via my windows phone.  Hyper-V and all of that stuff specified it was installed using a CoreInfo.exe file I got off the web to check to make sure the appropriate stuff was enabled.   Now after the 2 random virtual machine shutdowns the emulator is the only option showing when I want to debug.

Things checked:
Restarted both phone and virtual box OS.
Uninstalled device driver on the virtual box machine.
The 2.0 option is checked in the settings for the virtual box OS and can see the windows phone connected on the virtual machine via the device manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It mysteriously started working again where the windows phone was connected instead of to a 7.1 emulator.  I wish I could give a reason or an explanation to what I did to fix it but I didn't do anything to create this specific issue nor to fix it.  I put this up just in case anyone was reading it.